# How to create dynamic tree view in java

Tags: dynamic, treeview

I want to create tree view dynamically in java.

I am using two tables to do so.

1.parent-child relationship table.

2.Main table

My parent- child relationship table.

```
Parent  Child  
-------------------- 
1        2
1        3 
1        4
2        5
2        6
3        7 
3        8
5        9
5        10
```

My Main table

```
 Id      Name
 -------------------

  1      one
  2      two
  3      three
  4      four
  5      five
  6      six 
  7      seven
  8      eight
  9      nine
 10      ten
```

I want to display treeview as follows

```
one 
  two
   five
      nine
      ten
   six
  three
    seven
    eight
   four
```

please help me how to implement this dynamically.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you'll need to write a to string method which would be called for each parent and its children and then its children's children and so on for all the parents.

Comment: could you please give me sample code?

Comment: @4aRk Kn1gh7 could you please give me sample code